# Mongodb encode object error while inserting

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am running some python script in local jupyter and inserting dictionary as a document in mongodb(running on aws cloud) and its inserted successfully. but while running same code on cloud ubuntu instance then its throwing following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 482, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 610, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 0
```

Is there any pymongo version problem because local pymongo is 3.4 and cloud pymongo is 3.5